# how to use bundled program after pyinstaller --add-binary?

Tags: pyinstaller

I am trying to make an executable with pyinstaller, by issuing something like this:

`pyinstaller  -F  --add-binary="sometool.exe:."  myapp.py`

The build works fine. But, if I try to do something like:

`os.popen('sometool.exe')`, the error is that was not found.

So, how can I do that?

Comment: @JakubBláha I don't understand the ```.ico``` part - that just throws an error. The semicolon is for Windows and then it compiles properly (for me on Windows), however, just like the OP, I am unable to call ```sometool.exe``` in my script.

Comment: I don't really know, what I typed there :D

Answer (score 9):

For Unix like machine

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --log-level=WARN \
    --onefile --nowindow \
    --add-data="README:." \
    --add-data="image1.png:img" \
    --add-binary="libfoo.so:lib" \
    --hidden-import=secret1 \
    --hidden-import=secret2 \
    --upx-dir=/usr/local/share/ \
    myscript.spec
```

Or for Windows

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --log-level=WARN ^
    --onefile --nowindow ^
    --add-data="README;." ^
    --add-data="image1.png;img" ^
    --add-binary="libfoo.so;lib" ^
    --hidden-import=secret1 ^
    --hidden-import=secret2 ^
    --icon=..\MLNMFLCN.ICO ^
    myscript.spec
```

Official Doc: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html

I spent hours to figure out how to use `--add-binary` and finally got it working. Look at `--add-binary="libcrypto.dll:lib"`, you must add `:lib` as postfix.

Answer (score 5):

Try using this according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44352931) question:

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

And than in your app:

```
os.popen(resource_path('sometool.exe'))
```

This should work. I use this everyday :)

Answer (score 2):

For windows, you should use `;` instead of `:` before the binary file path.
like this :

```sh
pyinstaller  -F  --add-binary="sometool.exe;."  myapp.py
```