# Chromedriver Path Error when converting to .exe Pyinstaller

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pyinstaller

I am having an issue with Pyinstaller including the chromedriver when converting to .exe. The code works perfectly in python, does not work in the application.

I keep receiving this error:

```
(base) C:\Users\NDEERING\Desktop\Audit Assistant>"C:\Users\NDEERING\Desktop\Audi
t Assistant\dist\Audit Auto Beta.exe"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
  File "subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Beta.py", line 46, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)
  File "site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __ini
t__
  File "site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executabl
e needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chrome
driver/home
```

I have already formatted my code to switch to sys._MEIPASS.

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False): 
    # executed as a bundled exe, the driver is in the extracted folder
    chromedriver_path = os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, "chromedriver.exe")
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)
    IEdriver_path = os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, "IEDriverServer")
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(IEdriver_path)


chromedriver = "C:\\Users\\NDEERING\\Desktop\\Python\\chromedriver.exe"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver)
IeDriver = "C:\\Users\\NDEERING\\Desktop\\Python\\IEDriverServer.exe"
browseri = webdriver.Ie(executable_path=IeDriver)
```

and my .spec includes both of the drivers I am attempting to use:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['Beta.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\NDEERING\\Desktop\\Audit Assistant'],
             binaries=[('C:\\Users\\NDEERING\\Desktop\\Audit Assistant\\chromedriver.exe','Drivers'),('C:\\Users\\NDEERING\\Desktop\\Audit Assistant\\IEDriverServer.exe','Drivers')],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='Audit Auto Beta',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

I would like for the program to run properly on both my PC and other PC's.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pyi-archive-viewer](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced-topics.html#using-pyi-archive-viewer) to inspect the .exe file contents, my expectation is that you're adding binaries under `Drivers` folder and your Python script is looking for them in the current folder.

So something like:

```
chromedriver_path = os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, "Drivers/chromedriver.exe")
```

should do the trick for you.

More information:

- [PyInstaller: Advanced Topics](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced-topics.html#advanced-topics)
- [how to use bundled program after pyinstaller --add-binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48210090/how-to-use-bundled-program-after-pyinstaller-add-binary)
- [Selenium With Python](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Selenium+With+Python)