# Pyinstaller : Kivy: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clearcolor'

Tags: python-3.x, windows, kivy, pyinstaller, python-packaging

I am trying to package a kivy based python application for windows using `auto-py-to-exe`. auto-py-to-exe uses Pyinstaller for packaging. So after packaging the application and trying to run the created executable file of the application, I encounter this error:

```
File "desktop.py", line 356, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clearcolor'
```

which in the actual code in `desktop.py` refers to:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window

....something....

if __name__ == "__main__":
    .... something

    Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 0.99, 1)

    ....something
```

Here I am trying to provide close to white color background to the window.

I have checked for proper installation of `kivy` and availability of `kivy.core.window` module in site-packages of python.
I have read at severals places to use the package-name in `--hidden-import` as sometimes modules may not be picked due incorrect path or other issues, so I have tried passing this module as `--hidden-import "kivy.core.window"`  and also tried `--add-data` flag as `--add-data "C:/Python3/Lib/site-packages/kivy/core/window;window/"` to forcefully include kivy.core.window.
However no luck and I still getting the same error.

If I am not mistaken the above mentioned error means the code get `Nonetype` when it tries to access `window` although the module is present at right place i.e. after packaging it is present in the package along with other kivy modules.

Also when I run the script from some IDE it works fine.

I have followed [this](https://nitratine.net/blog/post/issues-when-using-auto-py-to-exe/#debugging) document for debugging the Pyinstaller warnings/errors.

Config: Windows10, Python3.4, kivy 1.11.1

What am I missing or how can I specify executable to look for the file at the correct path?

Comment: What happens if you remove this line?

Comment: @inclement After removing this line I get ` [CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.` . I have browsed this error and found different solution referring to sdl2.dll [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5677). So I went ahead and added .dll files for sdl2, glew and angle in ' PATH =   C:\Python3\share\sdl2\bin ` and so on for glew and angle. So all the .dll files are imported properly and it works fine. Thanks @inclement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after @inclement's comment : to remove the line
After removing this line I get  `[CRITICAL] [App ] Unable to get a Window, abort.` . I have browsed this error and found different solution referring to sdl2.dll [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5677). So I went ahead and added path to .dll files for sdl2, glew and angle in Windows environment variable path `PATH = C:\Python3\share\sdl2\bin` and so on for glew and angle. So all the .dll files are imported properly and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I use this way to solve it:

(If you don't want to find sdl2 bin path, you can use this way.)

```
pip install pygame
```

If you use custom spec, you will need to edit it to let pyinstaller rebuild exe.

I don't know how does it work, but it work for me.
(Pygame also use sdl2)
(My env: kivy 2.1.0, pyinstaller 5.1, conda env, python 3.7)

---

Or like answer above, but use some different way:

```
# In spec file, modify this line:
a = Analysis(
    ...
    binaries=[(r"Your_env_path\share\sdl2\bin\*.dll", ".")],
    ...
)
```

You can also use --add-binary argument.
[how to use bundled program after pyinstaller --add-binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48210090/how-to-use-bundled-program-after-pyinstaller-add-binary)

```
# In Unix
pyinstaller -w --add-binary="Your_env_path\share\sdl2\bin\*.dll:." -F main.py
```

```
# In Window
pyinstaller -w --add-binary="Your_env_path\share\sdl2\bin\*.dll;." -F main.py
```

---

Or following official way:

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-windows.html

"Editor and add these lines at the beginning of the spec"

```
# In spec file:
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew
exe = EXE(
    ...
    *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
    ...
)
```

---

My english is not good, hoping this conveys the correct meaning.