# PyInstaller CLI can't use added binary (an .exe) even though I have added it with --add-binary flag (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, miniconda

Using Windows, I have a python program that runs CMD within using `subprocess.Popen`. When I run it from python, it works. When I create the executable and run it, it doesn't find the tool I am using (`esptool`):

```
'esptool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

The command call I have built so far with `--add-binary` is as follows:

```
pyinstaller -F main.py -n "ProgramTest" -i resources/ico/icon.ico --add-binary "C:\\Users\\<my_user>\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\envs\\this_env\\Scripts\\esptool.exe;."
```

(I have obtained the path to `esptool` by running `where.exe esptool`. That's the only instance of `esptool` that appears.)

Also tried the solution listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48210090/how-to-use-bundled-program-after-pyinstaller-add-binary), where they use `=` after the flag (`--add-binary="..."`) and using `lib` as in `--add-binary="...;lib"`.

Perhaps it has something to do with my python environments? Maybe I am not adding correctly the executable?

The code to execute my cmd lines is as follows:

```py
import subprocess

def execute(cmd):
    popen = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True
    )
    for stdout_line in iter(popen.stdout.readline, ""):
        yield stdout_line
    popen.stdout.close()
    return popen.wait()
```

My environment:

- OS Name: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
- Version: Windows 10.0.19045 Build 19045
- miniconda: 23.1.0
- Python (env): 3.10.9
- PyInstaller: 5.8.0
- esptool: 3.1

Comment: What is the command you're sending to `execute`? Is the location of the EXE within the package in PATH? If not, you'll need to specify the complete path to the EXE when executing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem as [adding data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404744/determining-application-path-in-a-python-exe-generated-by-pyinstaller), you must create a relative path to the `.exe`.

To be able to run the command in both an `.exe` and as a python script, I used:

```py
def get_exe_path(exe_name):
    if getattr(sys, "frozen", False):
        application_path = os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, exe_name + ".exe")
    else:
        application_path = exe_name
    return application_path
```

Now, just by appending it at the beggining of the call I want to call, it works:

```py
ESPTOOL_PATH = get_exe_path("esptool")
order = ESPTOOL_PATH + " --port " + port + " --chip esp32 erase_flash"
```